# Rednering with glDrawArrays and glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

So I was playing around with an OpenGL project of mine when I noticed something strange. I was drawing multiple meshes to test some shaders but when I ran the code only one of the meshes was rendered.

I stepped through all my code and everything was being called and working correctly. The strangest part was that the two meshes would be drawn independently of each other but never together. After some digging I discovered what happened.

These meshes used different drawing methods. One was a "cube" mesh that was drawn with a VAO and glDrawElementsBaseVertex like so.

```
void ElementMesh::GenerateBuffers( const std::vector<unsigned short> &pIndices, const std::vector<Vector3<float>> &pVertices, const std::vector<Vector2<float>> pUVs, const std::vector<Vector3<float>> pNormals ) {
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &m_vao );
    glBindVertexArray( m_vao );

    glGenBuffers( NUM_BUFFERS, m_buffers );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffers[ VERTEX_BUFFER ] );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pVertices.size() * sizeof( Vector3<float> ), &pVertices[ 0 ], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffers[ TEX_COORD_BUFFER ] );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pUVs.size() * sizeof( Vector2<float> ), &pUVs[ 0 ], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffers[ NORMAL_BUFFER ] );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pNormals.size() * sizeof( Vector3<float> ), &pNormals[ 0 ], GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffers[ INDEX_BUFFER ] );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pIndices.size() * sizeof( unsigned short ), &pIndices[ 0 ], GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glBindVertexArray( 0 );
}

void ElementMesh::Render() const {
    glBindVertexArray( m_vao );
    glDrawElementsBaseVertex( GL_TRIANGLES, m_numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ( void* ) ( sizeof( unsigned short ) * m_baseIndex ), m_baseVertex );
    glBindVertexArray( 0 );
}
```

The code works and draws correctly, I've added it here as an example. The other "cube" mesh was made of just vertices though and is drawn with glDrawArrays like so.

```
void ArrayMesh::GenerateBuffers( Vector3<GLushort> *pVertex ) {
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_elements * sizeof *vertex, vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
}

void ArrayMesh::Render() const {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_elements );

    glDisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
}
```

Rendering...

```
void Renderer:Render() {
    m_shader1->Bind();
    m_shader1->UpdateUniforms( m_entity1->GetMVP(), m_entity1->GetTexture() );
    m_entity1->GetMesh()->Render();

    m_shader2->Bind();
    m_shader2->UpdateUnforms( m_entity2->GetMVP(), m_entity2->GetTexture() );
    m_entity2->GetMesh()->Render();
}
```

Like I said, both of these work independently of one another and only fail when used together.

So my question is, can glDrawElements and its other forms be used in conjunction with glDrawArrays and its other forms? And if so, what am I doing incorrectly that mine don't work? Is it the lake of a VAO in the second render?

Comment: What does "used together" mean? How would these two draw calls be "combined"?

Comment: They are just both being called at some point when rendering. They are two completely different meshes they are just drawn differently. I want one mesh to use glDrawArrays and another mesh to use glDrawElements which is what i mean by "used together." Does that make sense?

Comment: You should paste the relevant code then. The code pasted so far uses a VAO for one draw call, but does not explicitely set one for the other, otherwriting the vertex pointer of whatever VAO might be bound at that time.

Comment: I added the buffer generation code as well as the rendering code. entity1 uses glDrawElements, entity2 use glDrawArrays. If I comment out the 3 relevant lines of either one the opposite one draws, otherwise only one draws. This isn't a major problem and I was just curious if this was a thing in OpenGL where the two don't work together for some odd reason. I'm also developing on a Mac if that changes anything.

Comment: Have you tried using a VAO for the ArrayMesh? If not, try that.

Comment: @Dan I have not tried that. I will try later and let you know my results.

Comment: I agree with Dan. I've got a situation when I only see something on screen after initializing a VAO.

Comment: Using a VAO with the glDrawArrays worked perfectly! Thanks for all the help!